# mock the same method for multiple unit tests but want to return different results for the mocked method each time

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python unit test class.

I am testing `func_A` and `func_B`, both of which will call `func_X` that lives outside.
I want to mock the returned value of `func_X` **differently** for each of my unit tests.

I have something like below, but it does not work. I get the same mocked returned value `AAAA`.

I also tried starting up the patch in `setUp()` and stopping it in `tearDown()`, but this does not work either.

Any help is appreciated!!

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("mymodule.func_X", autospec=True)
    def test_A(self, func_X):
      func_X.return_value = "AAAA"
      func_A()
      ....
    @patch("mymodule.func_X", autospec=True)
    def test_B(self, func_X):
      func_X.return_value = "BBBB"
      func_B()
      ...
```

Comment: Perhaps I have a different idea of what a mock and function are supposed to be, or you need to take another input.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/function.html

Comment: @KennyOstrom That is not quite what is happening.

Comment: Why are you using `@decorator`? Shouldn't that be `@patch`? Also, can you show a sample of the code you are actually testing to get an idea of how it is actually running against the real code?

Comment: @idjaw you are right. it is "patch" not decorator.
the code snippet above is pretty much the real code I have.